# Adding the first digit(s) of a cell ending with specific letter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that has blocks of cells. I add them for a total if they don't contain any letter. Letters signify a specific variable or signifier code for tracking. I also want to add the cell value when a cell has an ending code letter. I've tried SUMIF, Substitute, SumProduct and a few others.

For a while I've used the following which worked till the S value changed to another number than "8" which then gave the wrong sum from the range.

`=if(countif(D64:Q64,"*S")=0,"",((countif(D64:Q64,"*S"))*8))`

In the cell range I have 5 variable groups ending in a letter (A, H, S, C and R) and one group not ending in any letter.

The formula I use to add the cells not containing a letter but have a value is this

`=IF(SUM(AA64,(SUMIF(D65:Q65,"<>")),-(COUNTIF(D65:Q65,">=0")*8))>24,24,(SUM(AA64,(SUMIF(D65:Q65,"<>")),-(COUNTIF(D65:Q65,">=0")*8))))`

which adds the table data plus the previous lines table data but does not exceed 24.

H is a set value of 6 and doesn't change.

Does anyone know how to add the value of the cells that contain a specific letter?

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | *N* (number) | A | S | C | R | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8.5 | H | 8A | 2S | 9 | 3C | 0.5R | 17.5 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 0.5 | 6 |

I'd prefer it be a formula usable in Google Sheets because that is where this data is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use this formula below column "N" then drag right until below column "H".

```
=SWITCH(H$1,"N",SUM($A2:$G2),"H",6,SUM(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(LEFT($A2:$G2,FIND(H$1,$A2:$G2)-1))),0)))
```

**This is a combination of three formulas:**

If the row above is N, sum A2 to G2. This will ignore all the strings.

If the row above is H, output 6.

Else, get the number to the left of the defined suffix, set all others to 0, and get the sum.

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

[Extract number from string in Google Sheets](https://www.spreadsheetclass.com/extract-text-or-numbers-from-a-string-in-google-sheets/)

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped but I need them to be separate formulas so I broke out the last part as the needed formula
`=SUM(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(LEFT($D64:$Q64,FIND("S",$D64:$Q64)-1))),0))`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A3:G3, isnumber(A3:G3))
```

to compute the sum of the cells with numbers only, and to use

```
=sum(filter(substitute($A$3:$G$3, I$2,)+0, regexmatch($A$3:$G$3, I$2)))
```

under the 'A' and drag to the right

---

### Examples

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]